# How to retrieve all child data in Firebase and show in xml layout

Tags: android, android-layout, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an App with `Firebase` in which user can add data and show the data directly from `Firebase Database`. Data is inserted successfully and it looks like this in database after each value inserted.

**This is the picture of my database:**

[image]

I want to retrieve all the data in Student (eg studentName & studentPhoneNumber) and displayed in a .xml layout file. Since i use `legacy SDK` in my code, i dont know how to use `DatabaseReference`.

```
   ShowButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            firebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Student student = postSnapshot.getValue(Student.class);

                        String ShowDataString =ShowDataTextView.getText()+ "Name : "+student.getStudentName()+"\nPhone Number : "+student.getStudentPhoneNumber()+"\n\n";

                        ShowDataTextView.setText(ShowDataString);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    System.out.println("Data Access Failed" + firebaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

**My Student.class look like this:**

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public Student() {

    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getStudentPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setStudentPhoneNumber(String phonenumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phonenumber;
    }

}
```

Comment: what error your getting?

Comment: @Benjithbinja it works but the app crash after i press ShowButton. Is this the cause of not using ArrayList in my code by any chance?

Comment: can you provide the error log and firebase reference upto where your given for listner?

Comment: i dont have firebase reference because i use legacy SDK (compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0').

Comment: please go through this  [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take student `arrayList` and add students data to list.

```
FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuthInstance = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser mFirebaseCurrentUser = mFirebaseAuthInstance.getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("User").child(mFirebaseCurrentUser.getUid()).child("Student");
        mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                ArrayList<Student> studentList=new ArrayList<Student>();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Student student = postSnapshot.getValue(Student.class);
                    studentList.add(student);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                System.out.println("Data Access Failed" + firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Use `RecylerView` to load data to xml,refer the below link to use `RecylerView`

> More [reference](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)

Comment: I have an error saying 'List' is abstract, cannot be instantiated at line studentList=new List<Student>();

Comment: try `List<Student> studentList=new ArrayList<Student>();`

Comment: use ArrayList as suggested by Ergin Erosy

Comment: @ErginErsoy   It has no error but the app crash after i use ShowButton

Comment: @zariphehe share your crash log

Comment: zariphehe please check with the updated answer and let me know.

Comment: @Shruti which part of log should i share? it is too long. Sorry, im new to this.

Comment: Ok np, read it! Is it NullPointerException? or firebase database permission denied error?

Comment: if you can share crash log we can check

Comment: @zariphehe if this answer is working,accept the answer otherwise share the crash log by searching with the keyword Fatal Error in log.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
public class FethingDatas extends AppCompatActivity {


    RecyclerView ry_fetchdata;

    Firebase firebase;

    ArrayList<Pojo_Recylerview> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    Pojo_Recylerview pojo_recylerview_obj;

    Display_Adapter display_adapter;

    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fething_datas);

        ry_fetchdata = findViewById(R.id.ry_fetchdata);


        firebase = new Firebase("https://fir-project-87eac.firebaseio.com/").child("Userdata");

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        ry_fetchdata.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        ry_fetchdata.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        display_adapter = new Display_Adapter(this,arrayList);
        ry_fetchdata.setAdapter(display_adapter);

        firebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                {

                    arrayList.clear();

                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {

                        String subject= (String) dataSnapshot1.child("subject").getValue();
                        String username = (String) dataSnapshot1.child("username").getValue();

                        pojo_recylerview_obj = new Pojo_Recylerview();

                        Log.d("subject","username"+subject +" "+username);

                        pojo_recylerview_obj.setSubject(subject);
                        pojo_recylerview_obj.setUsername(username);

                        arrayList.add(pojo_recylerview_obj);

                    }

                    display_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(FethingDatas.this,"No More Data Found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: i hope this will help you..for it's working fine..try this same procedure for you